Connection to MongoDB on Atlas: Timeout calling ismaster
The problem
How to access my MongoDB on Atlas from a Wolfram Notebook?
Following the Wolfram doc, I try this:
MongoConnect[<|
"Host"->"mongodb+srv://blu:XXXX@cluster0.wdvmm.mongodb.net/",
"CAFile"->$MongoDefaultCAFile
|>].

Unfortunately, this ends up in an error message from the Mongo C Driver saying:

$\color{red}{\text{No suitable servers found}}$,
$\color{red}{\text{Timeout calling ismaster on 'cluster0-shard-00-01.wdvmm.mongodb.net:27017}}$

Debug
1)Error in the Connection String? No.
According to the Mongo Shell, the Connection String is OK:
"mongodb+srv://blu:XXXX@cluster0.wdvmm.mongodb.net/"


2)Something on the local network?
According to HostLookup[] and Ping[], the Wolfram Notebook process is able to access the Mongo Server.

3)Does is work with Mathematica? Yes
I don't have Mathematica on my machine, but according to @Domen (see comment), the call reach the Mongo Server that replies "Authentication failed".
An idea: when executed with Mathematica, the request to the MongoDB server comes from the local computer, but when executed with Wolfram Cloud, it comes from a Wolfram server.
Can someone confirm this?

I think it is indeed Wolfram Cloud that is problematic. I get a different error (authentication failed) if I run your code in the desktop version of Mathematica. I strongly suggest you test your code on the desktop to see if the same problem appears.

I suggest you update your question with all the information you have about your troubleshooting process. Share the code you used to test and the response you get. Use the [edit] button. The comments should not become a long list of updates, so please delete the comments that become obsolete after your update. I will delete my comments. Think this Question should be useful not only for you but also for future readers.

I can confirm that MongoConnect to Atlas works fine on desktop, but it doesn't work on the Cloud (even after allowing access from any IP in Atlas). I suggest you contact Wolfram Technical Support, since the issue is specific to the Cloud, and it is unlikely we will be able to find a solution on our own ...

Thks Domen for your investigation. I'll refer to WTS!

Unfortunately, neither WTS nor the two authors of the package ever responded...
